# Out of memory (Neeeded xxxxxxxx bytes)

Tags: mysql, performance, configuration, settings

I ran a query from MySQL server with big data. It works in development (But the table is not as big as production). Now when I migrate it into Production, it seems like out of memory

```
Out of memory (Needed 89684760 bytes)
```

Which setting I can change to increase the memory limit for MySQL? 
I still got enough space on my server to utilize.

I tried to limit it works, but somehow my application need all the data...

I use MySQL 4.1 and also tried for increase key buffer size  and sort buffer size but no works

Comment: The MySQL 4.1 branch died 5 years ago. For God's sake stop using it.

Comment: its on production server and its used for many people.. its hard to migrate it cause too much module and script in it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know if any setting to increase the limit but i resolve this problem with code..

Idea  is to create temp table.

```
1. empty temp table
2. insert into with select query
3. query from temp table
```

it works finally.